# Insert element between ancestor and multiple descendants using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to convert

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1"></div>
  <div id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

into

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner1"></div>
    <div id="inner2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to preserve any references to the inner divs that may have been set prior to this so just doing `$("#outer").html($("<div id='middle>" + $("#outer").html() + "</div>"))` will not work for me.

Is there a better way than just creating the middle div, moving all the children of outer to it and then appending it to the outer div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this...

```
$('#outer').wrapInner($('<div>',{id:'middle'}));
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/uy6wg/

---

The [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) method will wrap all the content of `#outer` in the element you give it.

This will include inner text nodes if your actual content contains any.

---

If you care about performance, here's a native DOM solution...

```
var outer = document.getElementById('outer'),
    middle = document.createElement('div');

middle.id = 'middle';

while(outer.firstChild)
    middle.appendChild(outer.firstChild);

outer.appendChild(middle);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/uy6wg/1/

---

This could be made into a reusable function...

```
function wrapInner(id, tag) {
    var outer = document.getElementById(id),
        wrapper = document.createElement(tag);

    while(outer.firstChild)
        wrapper.appendChild(outer.firstChild);

    outer.appendChild(wrapper);
    return wrapper;
}
```

```
wrapInner('outer','div').id = "middle";
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/uy6wg/2/

Comment: +1: I didn't know about `.wrapInner()` (hence my answer recommending `.wrapAll()`).

Comment: @nnnnnn: `.wrapAll()` is a good solution too. You'd just want to be sure to select text nodes to be wrapped, though that isn't needed given OP's markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.wrapAll()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/):

```
$("#outer > div").wrapAll('<div id="middle"></div>');
```